# Add border to group of divs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi I have many divs in my HTML and I need to add border to certains divs, but I cant put all divs in a new container div:

[image]

Those boxes are simply divs so I need to put borders to every group.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {


console.log( "document loaded" );
});
```

```css
div.seatCharts-container {
 /*min-width: 700px;*/
}
div.seatCharts-cell {

 height: 16px;
 width: 16px;
 margin: 3px;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height:16px;
 color: blue;

}
div.seatCharts-seat {
 background-color: green;
 color: white;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 cursor: default;
}
div.seatCharts-seat:focus {
 border: none;
}
/*
.seatCharts-seat:focus {
 outline: none;
}
*/

div.seatCharts-space {
 background-color: white;
}
div.seatCharts-row {
 height: 50px;
}

div.seatCharts-row:after {
 clear: both;
}

div.seatCharts-seat.selected {
 background-color: aqua;
}

div.seatCharts-seat.focused {
 background-color: #6db131;
}

div.seatCharts-seat.available {
 background-color: green;
}

div.seatCharts-seat.unavailable {
 background-color: red;
 cursor: not-allowed;
}

ul.seatCharts-legendList {
 list-style: none;
}
li.seatCharts-legendItem {
 margin-top: 10px;
 line-height: 2;
}
div.sarasa {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
a {
 color: #b71a4c;
}
.front-indicator {
 width: 145px;
 margin: 5px 32px 15px 32px;
 background-color: #f6f6f6; 
 color: #adadad;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 3px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 500px;
 text-align: left;
}
.booking-details {
 float: left;
 text-align: left;
 margin-left: 35px;
 font-size: 12px;
 position: relative;
 height: 401px;
}
.booking-details h2 {
 margin: 25px 0 20px 0;
 font-size: 17px;
}
.booking-details h3 {
 margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
 font-size: 14px;
}
div.seatCharts-cell {
 color: #182C4E;
 height: 25px;
 width: 25px;
 line-height: 25px;
 
}
div.seatCharts-seat {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 cursor: pointer; 
}
div.seatCharts-row {
 height: 35px;
}
div.seatCharts-seat.available {
 background-color: #B9DEA0;
}
div.seatCharts-seat.empty-class {
 background-color: white;
}
div.seatCharts-seat.available.first-class {
/*  background: url(vip.png); */
 background-color: #3a78c3;
}
div.seatCharts-seat.available.focused {
 background-color: #76B474;
}
div.seatCharts-seat.selected {
 background-color: #E6CAC4;
}
div.seatCharts-seat.unavailable {
 background-color: #472B34;
}
section.seatCharts-container {
 border-right: 1px dotted #adadad;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 20px;
 float: left;
}
div.seatCharts-legend {
 padding-left: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 16px;
}
ul.seatCharts-legendList {
 padding-left: 0px;
}
span.seatCharts-legendDescription {
 margin-left: 5px;
 line-height: 30px;
}
.checkout-button {
 display: block;
 margin: 10px 0;
 font-size: 14px;
}
#selected-seats {
 max-height: 200px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: none;
 width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="seat-map1" style="width: 800px" class="seatCharts-container" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="1_8">
                <div class="front-indicator">Mapa de puestos</div>

            <div class="seatCharts-row"><div class="seatCharts-cell seatCharts-space hidden">1</div><div id="1_1" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class" titulo="PtoRaul">PtoRaul</div><div id="1_2" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available" titulo="PtoAngelo">PtoAngelo</div><div id="1_3" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="1_4" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="1_5" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="1_6" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class" titulo="PtoFax">PtoFax</div><div id="1_7" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="1_8" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="1_9" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="1_10" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="1_11" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="1_12" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="1_13" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="1_14" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div></div><div class="seatCharts-row"><div class="seatCharts-cell seatCharts-space hidden">2</div><div id="2_1" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available" titulo="PtoSOPIPC1">PtoSOPIPC1</div><div id="2_2" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class" titulo="PtoSOPIPC2">PtoSOPIPC2</div><div id="2_3" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="2_4" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="2_5" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available" titulo="PtoSOPSMS1">PtoSOPSMS1</div><div id="2_6" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class" titulo="PtoSOPSMS2">PtoSOPSMS2</div><div id="2_7" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="2_8" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="2_9" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="2_10" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="2_11" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="2_12" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="2_13" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="2_14" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div></div><div class="seatCharts-row"><div class="seatCharts-cell seatCharts-space hidden">3</div><div id="3_1" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class" titulo="PtoGonzalo">PtoGonzalo</div><div id="3_2" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class" titulo="PtoWalter">PtoWalter</div><div id="3_3" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="3_4" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="3_5" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="3_6" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="3_7" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="3_8" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="3_9" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="3_10" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="3_11" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="3_12" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="3_13" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="3_14" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div></div><div class="seatCharts-row"><div class="seatCharts-cell seatCharts-space hidden">4</div><div id="4_1" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available" titulo="PtoADMIN">PtoADMIN</div><div id="4_2" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class" titulo="PtoMarcos">PtoMarcos</div><div id="4_3" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="4_4" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="4_5" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="4_6" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="4_7" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="4_8" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="4_9" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="4_10" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="4_11" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="4_12" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="4_13" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="4_14" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div></div><div class="seatCharts-row"><div class="seatCharts-cell seatCharts-space hidden">5</div><div id="5_1" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="5_2" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="5_3" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="5_4" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="5_5" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="5_6" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class" titulo="ptoNuevo1234">ptoNuevo1234</div><div id="5_7" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="5_8" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="5_9" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="5_10" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="5_11" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="5_12" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="5_13" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="5_14" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div></div><div class="seatCharts-row"><div class="seatCharts-cell seatCharts-space hidden">6</div><div id="6_1" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="6_2" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="6_3" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="6_4" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="6_5" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="6_6" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="6_7" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="6_8" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="6_9" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="6_10" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="6_11" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="6_12" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="6_13" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="6_14" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div></div><div class="seatCharts-row"><div class="seatCharts-cell seatCharts-space hidden">7</div><div id="7_1" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="7_2" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="7_3" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="7_4" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="7_5" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="7_6" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="7_7" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="7_8" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="7_9" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="7_10" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="7_11" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="7_12" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="7_13" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="7_14" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div></div><div class="seatCharts-row"><div class="seatCharts-cell seatCharts-space hidden">8</div><div id="8_1" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="8_2" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="8_3" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="8_4" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="8_5" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="8_6" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="8_7" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="8_8" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="8_9" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="8_10" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="8_11" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="8_12" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="8_13" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="8_14" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div></div><div class="seatCharts-row"><div class="seatCharts-cell seatCharts-space hidden">9</div><div id="9_1" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="9_2" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="9_3" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="9_4" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="9_5" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="9_6" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="9_7" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="9_8" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="9_9" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="9_10" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="9_11" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="9_12" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div><div id="9_13" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell economy-class available"></div><div id="9_14" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell available economy-class"></div></div></section>
```

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: i am not sure if this is what you want and it's not finished, you still need to do the math for the top and bottom neighbours, but might be a place to start. https://jsfiddle.net/zcn8p5t8/4/

Answer (score 4):

U can give div's  multiple classes.

U can do something like

```
<div class="group">
<div class="group">
<div class="group">
```

And css:

```
group
{
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: i would add that the naming of the class could be more specific, as he could have more then on type of group. Also you forgot the '.' before class in your css.

Answer (score 2):

I would add a class like `.border` to the div's you need a border on. Each square can have it's own border that way.

You can't create a border around a grouping of div's though,  that is more complex and would be something where using SVG's would be better suited.

Comment: you are right, but do you know how I can do that? I mean with SVG's... thanks

Comment: It's not something I'm very familiar with.  There's lots of different ways to animate SVG, you can use inline commands, CSS & SASS, or JS libraries like [SnapSVG](http://snapsvg.io/).  I had a friend show me the app they built for a theatre company with their seat booking process built out with SVG.  Seems like a very similar thing you're trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable trough pure CSS, but it won't be as responsive as You would expect.

What You are trying to achieve can be done using a plugin called **[CSS Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)** and as @profa said, You should simply apply a few classes that will add a border around a specific selection of objects.

The plugin can help You align Your elements in such a way that they stack up next to each other so they can fill the empty space, without displacing the other groups.

Needless to say, there will be some planning around the grouping part. You must make sure that the selections you want surrounder by a border must be a whole object. You can find more information about this on their site.

Another plugin that might help You with that is called **[Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)**. I think that this is the better choice for Your project since You have some increments going on troughout Your table.

> ***In both cases, this task that you have at hand is not simply achievable trough plain CSS. Having some dynamic cell additions may disrupt Your flow while using such plugins without careful planning.***